# need help in making an object pooler

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object

im making an unity2d game and need an object pooler to generate the ground. however in this version, instead of generating the ground sprites individually, i need to generate a group of them in a specific layout. The pooler i have only generates them individually

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;
using System.Collections; 
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class ObjectPooler : MonoBehaviour
{

public GameObject pooledObject;
public int pooledamnt;
List<GameObject> pooledObjects;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    pooledObjects = new List<GameObject>();
    for (int i = 0; i < pooledamnt; i++)
    {
        GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
        obj.SetActive(false);
        pooledObjects.Add(obj);
    }

}
    public GameObject GetPooledObject()
    {
    for (int i = 0; i < pooledObjects.Count; i++)
    {
        if (pooledObjects[i].activeInHierarchy)
        {
            return pooledObjects[i];
        }
    }
            GameObject obj = (GameObject)Instantiate(pooledObject);
            obj.SetActive(false);
            pooledObjects.Add(obj);
            return obj;
        
    }

   

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
   
}
}
```

all help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In Unity, for each layout you want, you can make prefabs with your objects manually. Create an empty object and make your ground objects child of it. Then assign them

Like:

```
public List<GameObject> pooledObjects;
```